# FormsAuthentication.Authenticate() Utility?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

i can't see the utility of this function, because everybody save information about members on database and not in the **web.config** file, so we need all the time to write our own function to authenticate which checks if the user exists on the database with the corresponding password.

Comment: According to Microsoft it is obsolete: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are cases when you need to authenticate the user without asking him for the password. Here is the situation where I used it:

I have a website using the `asp:Login` control. I authenticate users using username and password on the click of the login button.

Then, I was asked to implement another type of login, parallel to the existing one (the user could choose), the one using **OpenID**.
So basically, after the email provider ensured me of the user's email, I automatically authenticated it without asking for username or password.

Something like:

```
if ((hasUsername(email)))
{
     FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);       
}
```